# Don't close modal when click outside form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new with coding etc.  I found a nice signup form on codepen which I would like to use for an private project.  What I want to change is that the modal should not close when the user presses the "esc" key or clicks outside the form. How can I do that?

The link of the codepen is this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/pIrbg)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $form_modal = $('.cd-user-modal'),
        $form_login = $form_modal.find('#cd-login'),
        $form_signup = $form_modal.find('#cd-signup'),
        $form_forgot_password = $form_modal.find('#cd-reset-password'),
        $form_modal_tab = $('.cd-switcher'),
        $tab_login = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(0).children('a'),
        $tab_signup = $form_modal_tab.children('li').eq(1).children('a'),
        $forgot_password_link = $form_login.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $back_to_login_link = $form_forgot_password.find('.cd-form-bottom-message a'),
        $main_nav = $('.main-nav');

    //open modal
    $main_nav.on('click', function(event){

        if( $(event.target).is($main_nav) ) {
            // on mobile open the submenu
            $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            // on mobile close submenu
            $main_nav.children('ul').removeClass('is-visible');
            //show modal layer
            $form_modal.addClass('is-visible'); 
            //show the selected form
            ( $(event.target).is('.cd-signup') ) ? signup_selected() : login_selected();
        }

    });

    //close modal
    $('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }   
    });
    //close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });

    //switch from a tab to another
    $form_modal_tab.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ( $(event.target).is( $tab_login ) ) ? login_selected() : signup_selected();
    });

    //hide or show password
    $('.hide-password').on('click', function(){
        var $this= $(this),
            $password_field = $this.prev('input');

        ( 'password' == $password_field.attr('type') ) ? $password_field.attr('type', 'text') : $password_field.attr('type', 'password');
        ( 'Hide' == $this.text() ) ? $this.text('Show') : $this.text('Hide');
        //focus and move cursor to the end of input field
        $password_field.putCursorAtEnd();
    });

    //show forgot-password form 
    $forgot_password_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        forgot_password_selected();
    });

    //back to login from the forgot-password form
    $back_to_login_link.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        login_selected();
    });

    function login_selected(){
        $form_login.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.addClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.removeClass('selected');
    }

    function signup_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.addClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.removeClass('is-selected');
        $tab_login.removeClass('selected');
        $tab_signup.addClass('selected');
    }

    function forgot_password_selected(){
        $form_login.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_signup.removeClass('is-selected');
        $form_forgot_password.addClass('is-selected');
    }

    //REMOVE THIS - it's just to show error messages 
    $form_login.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_login.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
    $form_signup.find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $form_signup.find('input[type="email"]').toggleClass('has-error').next('span').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });


    //IE9 placeholder fallback
    //credits http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }

});


//credits https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/
jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // If this function exists...
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            // ... then use it (Doesn't work in IE)
            // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about whether a carriage return is one character or two. Sigh.
            var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        } else {
            // ... otherwise replace the contents with itself
            // (Doesn't work in Google Chrome)
            $(this).val($(this).val());
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How the user will close the modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this lines of code:

```
//close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == '27') {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

And change this:

from:

```
//close modal
$('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }   
});
```

to:

```
//close modal
$('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-close-form')) {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: thx gregor for your answer. It helped me a lot.  Is there a way that i could redirect the users to another page when they click on "create account" at the signup tab ?

Comment: It really depends, what you want to do and how your app/site is structured. You can navigate to another page on the client or you can do that on the server. On the client you can do something like this with jQuery, since you are already using jQuery: $( ".cd-form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); // your send the data logic window.location = "https://www.example.com"
});

Answer (score 0):

To stop the modal from closing with the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key you have to remove the below code. This code binds the keyup event to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which=='27'){
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

To prevent the outside click closing the dialog, remove this `$(event.target).is($form_modal)` condition from the `if` statement from the below code block. Through this statement, JS identifies the click context. So updated

```
$('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
   // Remove $(event.target).is($form_modal) condition from below
    if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from the existing javascript code.

```
  //close modal
$('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is($form_modal) || $(event.target).is('.cd-close-form') ) {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }   
});
//close modal when clicking the esc keyboard button
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which=='27'){
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change line 32 to

```
    //close modal
$('.cd-user-modal').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-close-form')) {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

and remove line 37

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == '27') {
        $form_modal.removeClass('is-visible');
    }
});
```

that's it